# How can update my custom theme when I update jquery-ui?

Tags: jquery-ui, themes

I updated jquery and jquery-ui from versions 1.7.2 and 1.8.23 to 1.9.1 and 1.10.3, respectively. Of course, with this my custom rolled theme no longer works.

Is there a way to update my theme to work with the new version without rolling a new one from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the css file that came with your custom theme.

In the top of the file you will find a comment that says:

To view and modify this theme, visit [**followed by a really long link to the jqueryUI theme roller**].

Here is an example for the [start](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/?ffDefault=Verdana,Arial,sans-serif&fwDefault=normal&fsDefault=1.1em&cornerRadius=5px&bgColorHeader=2191c0&bgTextureHeader=gloss_wave&bgImgOpacityHeader=75&borderColorHeader=4297d7&fcHeader=eaf5f7&iconColorHeader=d8e7f3&bgColorContent=fcfdfd&bgTextureContent=inset_hard&bgImgOpacityContent=100&borderColorContent=a6c9e2&fcContent=222222&iconColorContent=0078ae&bgColorDefault=0078ae&bgTextureDefault=glass&bgImgOpacityDefault=45&borderColorDefault=77d5f7&fcDefault=ffffff&iconColorDefault=e0fdff&bgColorHover=79c9ec&bgTextureHover=glass&bgImgOpacityHover=75&borderColorHover=448dae&fcHover=026890&iconColorHover=056b93&bgColorActive=6eac2c&bgTextureActive=gloss_wave&bgImgOpacityActive=50&borderColorActive=acdd4a&fcActive=ffffff&iconColorActive=f5e175&bgColorHighlight=f8da4e&bgTextureHighlight=glass&bgImgOpacityHighlight=55&borderColorHighlight=fcd113&fcHighlight=915608&iconColorHighlight=f7a50d&bgColorError=e14f1c&bgTextureError=gloss_wave&bgImgOpacityError=45&borderColorError=cd0a0a&fcError=ffffff&iconColorError=fcd113&bgColorOverlay=aaaaaa&bgTextureOverlay=flat&bgImgOpacityOverlay=75&opacityOverlay=30&bgColorShadow=999999&bgTextureShadow=flat&bgImgOpacityShadow=55&opacityShadow=45&thicknessShadow=0px&offsetTopShadow=5px&offsetLeftShadow=5px&cornerRadiusShadow=5px) theme.

Navigating to that link will bring you back to the Theme Roller with all your settings preloaded to match your theme.

Simply Re-roll the theme as if you just started from scratch and replace the previous CSS (and image files if necessary) with the ones you just generated.

Comment: Awesome! Excellent. The simplest answer is often the correct one!